# How to generate key in HSM with IAIK PKCS11 library

Tags: java, pkcs#11, hsm, iaik-jce

I am using the IAIK wrapper to send pkcs11 requests to my Bull HSM. My objective is to generate a consistent key (token = true). The problem is that I always have this error code:

`Exception in thread "main" iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY`

I can't understand why it's read-only? To initialize my Session I do so (using the RW_SESSION option):

```
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Mechanism;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Module;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Session;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Token;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.TokenException;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.objects.AESSecretKey;
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Constants;

...

static String libP11 = "nethsm.dll";
static String hsmPassword = "123456";
static int hsmSlotId = 1;

private static void initHSM() throws IOException, TokenException{
    Module module = Module.getInstance(libP11);
    module.initialize(null);
    Token token = module.getSlotList(Module.SlotRequirement.TOKEN_PRESENT)[hsmSlotId - 1].getToken();
    session = token.openSession(Token.SessionType.SERIAL_SESSION, Token.SessionReadWriteBehavior.RW_SESSION, null,
                null);

    session.login(Session.UserType.USER, hsmPassword.toCharArray());

}
```

My function to generate the key is the following:

```
private static AESSecretKey generateAESKey(byte[] keyValue, String label, int keyLength, boolean token) throws TokenException {
    Mechanism keyGenerationMechanism = Mechanism.get(PKCS11Constants.CKM_AES_KEY_GEN);

    AESSecretKey secretKeyTemplate = new AESSecretKey();
    secretKeyTemplate.getValueLen().setLongValue(new Long(keyLength));
    secretKeyTemplate.getLabel().setCharArrayValue(label.toCharArray());
    secretKeyTemplate.getToken().setBooleanValue(token);
    secretKeyTemplate.getSensitive().setBooleanValue(Boolean.FALSE);
    secretKeyTemplate.getExtractable().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
    secretKeyTemplate.getDerive().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
    secretKeyTemplate.getModifiable().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
    secretKeyTemplate.getEncrypt().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
    secretKeyTemplate.getDecrypt().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
    secretKeyTemplate.getUnwrap().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
    secretKeyTemplate.getWrap().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
    secretKeyTemplate.getSign().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);
    secretKeyTemplate.getVerify().setBooleanValue(Boolean.TRUE);

    secretKeyTemplate.getValue().setByteArrayValue(keyValue);

    return (AESSecretKey) session.generateKey(keyGenerationMechanism, secretKeyTemplate);
}
```

Any solutions please?

Comment: You should not call the IAIK code directly. The whole idea is that it is a PKCS#11 provider that lives behind the Java API interfaces. You should be calling the Java API. A side-advantage of that is that you will find working examples much more readily.

Comment: As far as I can remember `sensitive` and `extractable` may be the reason of your error. Try to exclude them from template and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to use:

```
secretKeyTemplate.getValue().setByteArrayValue(keyValue)
```

to set key value (`CKA_VALUE` in PKCS#11) while **generating** new key -- HSM will generate key value for you. Remove this line.

---

Note: If you want to **create** key with a given value try `C_CreateObject` ([`Session.createObject`](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/current/iaik/pkcs/pkcs11/Session.html#createObject-iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.objects.Object-) in IAIK Wrapper) instead -- but not all HSMs support this way. If you fail to create key with a known value using this method you will have to use `C_UnwrapKey` to import encrypted key value which usually works.

Good luck with your project!